# If $f$ is a homeomorphism then any periodic point have period less or equal 2

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

How can one prove the following statement?

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a homeomorphism. If $x\in\operatorname{Per}(f)$ then the period of $x$ can't be greater than $2$, i.e, $f(x)=x$ or $f^2(x)=x$.

Comment: What does the Per notation mean? Fixed points?

Comment: The set of periodic points, i.e, the set of points $x$ such that $f^n(x)=x$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f$ must be strictly monotonic, otherwise it cannot be bijective and continuous.

If $f$ is a homeomorphism, then so is $f^n$.

If $f$ is strictly increasing, then any periodic point must have period 1. If not, and $x$ is a fixed point of $f^n$ (but not $f^{n-1}$), then either $x< f(x) < f^2(x) < \cdots < f^n(x) = x$, or
$x> f(x) > f^2(x) > \cdots > f^n(x) = x$ which gives a contradiction.

So, we can assume that  $f$ is strictly decreasing.

Then $f^{2n}$ is strictly increasing and $f^{2n+1}$ is strictly decreasing.

The intermediate value theorem shows that $f$ has a fixed point and since $f$ is strictly decreasing, this fixed point is unique. Since this fixed point is
also a fixed point of $f^{2n+1}$, the fact that $f^{2n+1}$ is strictly decreasing shows that the unique fixed point of $f^{2n+1}$ is the same as the
fixed point of $f$, and in particular must have period 1.

Since $f^2$ is strictly increasing, the periodic points of $f^2$ must have period 1. This shows that any fixed point of $f^{2n}$ must also be a fixed
point of $f^2$.

Hence we have $\operatorname{Per}(f) = \{ x | f(x) =x \} \cup \{ x | f^2(x) = x \}$.

Comment: I don't see why the chain of inequalities hold, this is not a consequence of $f$ being strictly increasing, isn't it? And why if $f$ is strictly decreasing, $f^{2n}$ and $f^{2n+1}$ are strictly increasing and decreasing respectively? It must have the same monotony as $f$ I think.

Comment: Well, if you have some cycle $x_1,...,x_n$ with $x_{i+1} = f(x_i)$ and $x_1 = f(x_n)$ then if $x_1 < x_2$ you must have $x_2=f(x_1) < f(x_2) = x_3$, etc.

Comment: It is straightforward to show that if $g$ is increasing and $h$ is decreasing then $h \circ g$ is decreasing. If $k$ is increasing then $k \circ g$ is also increasing.